# python3 requests.delete giving 401 Unauthorised for bearer token but working fine in postman for keycloak user session delete endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, keycloak

I have flask app running in docker container in **http://localhost:5000/** and keycloak is running as docker container in **http://localhost:8080/** both in my local machine. I want to delete users session in keycloak with session delete endpoint.

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/sessions/<session_id>
```

my code

```
from flask import jsonify, session, request
import requests


@route("/delete_user_session")
def delete_user_session():

    token_body = {"grant_type": "refresh_token", "refresh_token": session_details["refresh_token"], "client_id": "admin-log",
          "client_secret": "eb13be11-0b7d-49e5-a88ae99a-343245j4543"}

    x = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", data=token_body) # this is working fine and is giving the tokens

    session_id = session.get("session_state")
    url_d = "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/sessions/{}".format(session_id)

    h = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(x.json()["access_token"]), "content-type": "application/json",
     "User-Agent": request.headers.get("User-Agent"),
     "Accept-Encoding": request.headers.get("Accept-Encoding"), 'cache-control': "no-cache"}

    res = requests.delete(url_d, headers=h)

    print(res.content)  #gives error {"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorised"}

    return jsonify({"message": "deleted"})
```

it is working fine with the **postman**. session is getting deleted as expected but with python requests module i am getting `401 unauthorised error`. though i am giving same bearer token in headers like in postman.

Below is the postman screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jBnO.png)

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the same cliendID in both postman and python  "admin-log" ?

Comment: @dreamcrash ya using same credentials with postman and python requests.